# How can I add boot jar location in the device tree?

Tags: android-source, android-soong

I have the mediatek-common.jar. I need to write a makefile to put the bootjar so that the following doesn't occur.

```
FAILED: ninja: 'out/soong/missing', needed by 'out/soong/ra6/dex_bootjars_input/
mediatek-common.jar', missing and no known rule to make it
12:28:59 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I have tried PRODUCT_COPY but still it says out/soong/missing is needed

Answer (score 0):

In android 10,if you want to add boot jar,java lib must be source file not ".jar",and make sure your target java lib's Android.bp have this statement:`installable: true`